# TYPO3 backend button call php function/action

Tags: php, typo3

I've created a backend button in my extension which looks like this:

```
class ButtonBarHook {

    public function getButtons(array $params, ButtonBar $buttonBar) {
        $buttons = $params['buttons'];

        $iconFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(IconFactory::class);
        $playController = new PlayController();
        $button = $buttonBar->makeLinkButton();
        $button->setIcon($iconFactory->getIcon('actions-document-export-csv', Icon::SIZE_SMALL));
        $button->setTitle('Export als XML');
        $button->setHref(***Link to my function***);

        $buttons[ButtonBar::BUTTON_POSITION_LEFT][1][] = $button;

        return $buttons;
    }
}
```

So far so good. It appears in the backend of TYPO3. Now I want to link the button to call a php function I wrote in a different class. I already tried `$button->setOnClick()`but this only creates a javascript onClick event.

I think `$button->setHref()` is the better approach but I don't know what to put in here.

How can I link to my php function/action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

)

You have to link to  a module or ajax route, that you have  registered

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/CoreArchitecture/Backend/Routing/Index.html

And then you can use the method `BackendUtility::getModuleUrl` method to get a path to insert into `setHref`